# Why does R add a prefix to my column name?

Tags: r

When I import my csv file into R, the first column's name changes from Species to i..Species but the i has two dots over it.

```
setwd("C:\\Users\\susan\\Google Drive\\Wood.harvesting.Project\\Wood Density")
Wood.Dens <- read.csv("Wood Density GCFR.csv")
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)

Wood.Dens
#> ï..Species      Date Sampling.area                     Veg.Type Number
```

Comment: Use `Wood.Dens <- read.csv("Wood Density GCFR.csv", encoding = "UTF-8")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This comes because your file encoding is `UTF-8`. To get rid of this you can use

```
library(readr)
Wood.Dens <- read_csv("Wood Density GCFR.csv")
```

Comment: Hi Bappa Thank you so much, worked like a charm. What is UTF-8?